# Обновление сгенерированного кода по базе данных в Linq2Sql

Tags: linq2sql, c#

Нигде в дизайнере не нашёл такой кнопочки.

Перегенерировать с использованием чего-то типа SQL Metal нельзя, т.к., во-первых, генерировать нужно выборочно, во-вторых, имена таблиц и свойств у меня отличаются от имён классов. Обновлять контекст вручную прямо в дизайнере муторно и опасно, я уже нарывался на трудно отлавливаемый баг в результате такого подхода.

Comment: можно поинтересоваться из-за чего вам необходимо проводить подобные манипуляции?

Comment: Как из-за чего? Новые требования, новая структура БД.

Comment: т.е. вы изменили структуру БД, а изменять DataContext хотите автоматически?

Comment: Ну как бы да. В принципе, довольно несложно написать свой кодогенератор для Linq2Sql, но если есть такая кнопочка, хорошо бы обойтись без этого.

Comment: но вам всё равно прийдётся переделывать все участки кода, где DataContext принимает участие

Comment: Конечно. Но это будет контролироваться на этапе компиляции. А если контекст не соответствует БД - ошибка произойдёт на этапе выполнения.